# Substracting one image band from subsequent using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, modis, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to find the day of year (DOY) for each year with the highest change in NDVI compared to the day before, to map in the end a shift in start of season.

My code to separate each year so far (returns a list with 18 ImageCollections with unknown elements):

```
    var months = ee.List.sequence(0, 17).map(function(n) {
      var start = ee.Date('2001-01-01').advance(n, 'year');
      var end = start.advance(1, 'year');
        return ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13A1").select("NDVI").filterDate(start, end);
    });
```

Subsequently I would like to subtract each NDVI-image from the previous one and compare to get the DOY of the biggest result.

Any ideas how to do that?